# Devise - Listing Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, model, devise, controller

in my rails app I need to list the users by username, the error I get is

```
NoMethodError in Posts#index

Showing C:/Users/Corey/Dev/statlog/app/views/posts/index.html.erb where line #12 raised:

undefined method `username' for #<Array:0x3893298>
Extracted source (around line #12):

9: <div class="follow-row">
10:   <div class="titan-users nuvo"><h2>TITAN Users</h2></div>
11:     <% @users.each do |post| %>
12:       <div class="user-row"><%= @user.username %></div>
13:     <% end %>
14: </div>
15: 
Rails.root: C:/Users/Corey/Dev/statlog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/posts/index.html.erb:12:in `block in _app_views_posts_index_html_erb___134739565_23193672'
app/views/posts/index.html.erb:11:in `each'
app/views/posts/index.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_posts_index_html_erb___134739565_23193672'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:13:in `index'
```

Down below is my posts_controller ya see I don't have a user_controller.

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
    @post = Post.new

    @users = User.all


    @user = User.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    redirect_to posts_path
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  # GET /posts/new.json
  def new
    @post = Post.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /posts/1
  # PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my user and post model.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :status, :author, :email, :username

  belongs_to :user

  validates :status, :presence => true



end
```

My user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username

  has_many :posts
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

Last but not least my post/index.html.erb view.

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <h1 id="welcome" class="nuvo">Welcome <%= current_user.username %>!</h1>
<% else %>
  <h1 id="welcome" class="nuvo">Log-In to make some posts!</h1>
<% end%>

<div class="follow-row">
  <div class="titan-users nuvo"><h2>TITAN Users</h2></div>
    <% @users.each do |post| %>
      <div class="user-row"><%= @user.username %></div>
    <% end %>
</div>

<div class="statuses">
  <% if user_signed_in? %><div class="status-form"><%= render 'form' %></div><% end %>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="post">
      <div class="tstamp"><strong>Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago by <%= post.user.username %></strong></div>
      <div class="status"><%= post.status %></div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My user migration file

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at

      ## Token authenticatable
      # t.string :authentication_token


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end
end
```

Add username to user migration file

```
class AddUsernameToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :username, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: can you paste your user migration file? is there a username declared?

Comment: just put it into the bottom of my question

Comment: could you `rails c` and then type `User`, and then paste the response here?

Comment: => User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_
token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime,
 sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetim
e, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, u
pdated_at: datetime, username: string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have in controller `@user = User.find(:all)` so when you call `@user.username` you get your lovely error.

Also in `<% @users.each do |post| %>` you have copy-pasted error (what is `post` doing here?). Use local `user` when rendering. **RadBrad** answer will work:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
   <div class="user-row"><%= user.username %></div>
<% end %>
```

This `@posts.users` won't work because you don't have that relation in your models.

Finally clean-up your controller and remove `@user = User.find(:all)`

Comment: No longer supported in rails5
`@user = User.find(:all)`

please use 

`@users = User.all`

`<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.email %>
<% end %>`

Answer (score 6):

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
   <div class="user-row"><%= user.username %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That just spits up the error `undefined local variable or method user for #<#<Class:0x37f9470>:0x38a8a30>`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
<% @posts.users.each do |post| %>
   <%= user.username %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<% @users.each do |post| %>
  <div class="user-row"><%= post.username %></div>
<% end %>
```

or you may also do this:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <div class="user-row"><%= user.username %></div>
<% end %>
```